# How to display a modal from a submit button in WTForms?

Tags: python, forms, flask, modal-dialog, flask-wtforms

I am writing a **Flask** Web Application and I have an `html` file with the view of a form from **WTForms**. Inside the file it is also defined a **modal** (`myModal`). **How to call it when I press the 'submit' button?**

I would expect it to be inside my `@route` function like this:

```
@posts.route("/my-page", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def mypage():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Execute operations with form
        # display the 'myModal' with results from the operations
        render_modal('myModal', results=results)  # Something like this?
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a variable to the underling template to show you want the modal triggered in that template.

```
@posts.route("/my-page", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def mypage():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Execute operations with form
        # display the 'myModal' in the underlying template with results from the operations
        return render_template('underlying_template.html', results=results, show_modal=True)  # Something like this?
```

And in your html file have something like the following (example is for Bootstrap 3):

```
   <script>
        {% if show_modal %}
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            });
        {% endif %}
    </script>
```